# Bool To Image Converter not displaying image at Design Time

Tags: c#, wpf

The BoolToImage converter works perfect at run-time, changes the ImageSource of the Image object according to the binding to a boolean property that gets toggled when the button is clicked. At design-time the VS designer will not display the image returned by the converter. Why? The TrueImageProperty and FalseImageProperty are static and they have default values. Why isn't at least the default ImageSource returned and displayed in the VS designer???

The converter:

```
namespace BoolToImageConverterTestApp
{
[ValueConversion (typeof (bool), typeof (ImageSource))]
public class BoolToImageConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TrueImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register ("TrueImage", typeof (ImageSource), typeof (BoolToImageConverter), new UIPropertyMetadata ((ImageSource)new BitmapImage (new Uri ("pack://application:,,,/BoolToImageConverterTestApp;component/green_led.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FalseImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register ("FalseImage", typeof (ImageSource), typeof (BoolToImageConverter), new UIPropertyMetadata ((ImageSource)new BitmapImage (new Uri ("pack://application:,,,/BoolToImageConverterTestApp;component/gray_led.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))));

    public ImageSource TrueImage
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue (TrueImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue (TrueImageProperty, value); }
    }

    public ImageSource FalseImage
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue (FalseImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue (FalseImageProperty, value); }
    }

    private const string Invert = "Invert";

    public object Convert (object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ( targetType != typeof (ImageSource) )
            throw new InvalidOperationException ("The target must be a ImageSource");

        if ( (value == null) || (value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) )
        {
            if ( FalseImage != null )
                return FalseImage;
            else
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        bool? bValue = (bool?)value;

        if ( (parameter != null) && ((parameter as string) == Invert) )
            bValue = !bValue;

        if ( bValue.Value )
        {
            if ( TrueImage != null )
                return this.TrueImage;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( FalseImage != null )
                return this.FalseImage;
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack (object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ("BoolToImageConverter ConvertBack not implemented - use OneWay binding");
    }
}
```

}

Test app XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BoolToImageConverterTestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BoolToImageConverterTestApp"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToImageConverter x:Key="RollFeedImageConverter" TrueImage="roll_feed_closed.png" FalseImage="roll_feed_opened.png"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition  Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition  Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image x:Name="TestImage" Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Path=SomeBoolValue, Converter={StaticResource RollFeedImageConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" Stretch="None"/>
    <Button x:Name="TestButton" Grid.Row="1" Content="Toggle Image" Margin="20" Click="TestButton_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Test app code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace BoolToImageConverterTestApp
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow ()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    public bool SomeBoolValue
    {
        get { return _someBoolValue; }
        set
        {
            if ( _someBoolValue != value )
            {
                _someBoolValue = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged ("SomeBoolValue");
            }
        }
    }
    private bool _someBoolValue = false;

    private void TestButton_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SomeBoolValue ^= true;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the PropertyChange event for the property specified
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Property name to update. Is case-sensitive.</param>
    public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged (string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged (propertyName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when a property on this object has a new value.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged (string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ( handler != null )
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs (propertyName);
            handler (this, e);
        }
    }

    #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
}
}
```

Project layout:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYaLm.png)

Comment: You're overriding the image values in your xaml with roll_feed_closed.png and roll_feed_opened.png. You need to use pack syntax there. Just some friendly advice, but I'd learn MVVM and proper WPF data binding. You're going down a rabbit hole the way your code is structured. A better approach would be to use triggers.

Comment: The "pack syntax" part is not true. The XAML parser will automatically add the missing Uri components. And the "converter works perfect at run-time".

Comment: I wouldn't do this with a Binding Converter at all. You may perhaps better use an Image Style with a DataTrigger on the SomeBoolValue, with a Setter for the Source property.

Comment: Agreed you should be using triggers, there's simply no need for a converter here.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This is just a simple example of the problem, or rather issue I am trying to understand better. I agree, if this was all I was trying to accomplish then a style with some triggers would be more straight forward. I'm actually using this converter on a custom control that already has styles associated with it, along with it's own Image property that is of type ImageSource. It is this property that I using the converter on.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a converter simply use a trigger like this:

```
<Image x:Name="TestImage" Grid.Row="0" Stretch="None">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="roll_feed_opened.png"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeBoolValue}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="roll_feed_closed.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the ideas. I really just want to try to understand what happens at design-time vs run-time. Why doesn't the converter at least return the default image for dependency property? Do resources not get created at design-time? Does the window's constructor not get called at design-time, and therefore the DataContext does not get set? I'm just learning about design-time d:DataContext and d:DesignData and d:DesignInstance. Using a d:DesignInstance I can actually get the converter to return the images I want in the VS designer.